# CaseComment and CaseHistory relatedlist in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, case, related-list

I want to add CaseComment and CaseHistory related list to my visualforce page.

<apex:relatedList list=" " />

What should be the value for List attribute in the code defined above. When I added

<apex:relatedList list="CaseHistory" /> 'Histories' is also not working 
 
<apex:relatedList list="CaseComment" /> 'CaseComments' is also not working

I get errors saying they are not valid child relationship name for entity Case.

Please help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with this and works for me.

```
  <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!case.casecomments}"var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.commentbody}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!case.Histories}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.OldValue}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.NewValue}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggets you create own history related list.
You can refer this [link](http://www.iterativelogic.com/create-your-own-history-related-list-in-visualforce/)

Comment: I can build it, but the reqmt is to build without using VF or apex. I need to use apex:relatedList

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through custom controller. Please refer this link. [Case History](http://kandhakatla.blogspot.in/2012/01/case-history-related-list.html)